# How to use Typescript to type a class such that a function can only interact on the classes properties and respect the properties' types?

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to type a class in a project I'm working on and looking for some expert help. While I do want to specifically know if it's possible to do what I'm asking (and how obviously), I am also open to advice on better ways to approach the problem.

My class has properties and a method to update these properties *while also doing some side effects*. It's due to the side effects I'm not just writing `Foo.prop = "new val"`.

So, given a class:

```js
class MyClass {
  prop1: string = "initial";
  prop2: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  update(key: ???, value: ???) {
    this[key] = value;
    this.doSomeSideEffects();
  }

  doSomeSideEffects() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in my code I'd like to call `myClass.update('prop1', 'new string');` or something like that.

1. How do I ensure that the `key` is a valid prop of the class and that the `value` is a valid type for the given prop?
2. Is there a better way to do this that doesn't use magicky strings for the prop name/key?

So far I've come up with adding an interface and getting the keys off of that.

```js
interface IMyClass {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: boolean;
}
type UpdateKeys = keyof IMyClass;

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
  ...
  update(key: UpdateKeys, value: typeof IMyClass[UpdateKeys]) {
    (this[key] as IMyClass[UpdateKeys]) = value;
    ...
  }
}
```

This allows intellisense to be more helpful when I call `myClass.update()` as it knows what keys are allowed, but the value type is `string | boolean` and it doesn't narrow that based on the prop passed. Plus, using `as` to typecast always feels like I could find a better way. (Though, as a bonus, using the interface helps me keep the class in sync slightly better?)

A last method I've thought of trying is to overload `update()` for each class property, but that is just going to get messy as more props are added (this class will hold configuration, so is going to grow over time).

```js
class MyClass {
  ...
  update(key: "prop1", value: string);
  update(key: "prop2", value: boolean);
  update(key, value) { ...
```

Sorry this got so long! I wanted to make sure it was all well explained :)
TIA for the advice and help!

---

*Edit: * The accepted answer also adds in a way to keep class methods from being allowed as the key for the `update` method, thus restricting it to only class properties. (This wasn't something I realised I wanted until seeing how the IDE handled the generic implementation)

Comment: I'd suggest making it generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp8jXm); does that work for you or am I missing something?  If it works as-is I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, let me know.

Comment: Such a simple answer for such a big write-up! :D yes I think that is it! I had tried generics, but my mental model for them isn't great and I either way overcomplicated the attempt or just did it wrong.

Along with that, is it possible to "remove" `update` and `doSideEffects` from `K` so that the IDE doesn't list them as valid options with intellisense? Least of my worries, tbh, especially since the value signature won't match other properties.
Thanks!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer.  As for removing those keys, I'd do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXzODm). Is that part of the current question (if so then please [edit] to make that clear) or a followup question (in which case I won't belabor the point in my answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I'd probably take here would be to make `update()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of `key`, which should be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be [known keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) of the current object:

```
update<K extends keyof this>(key: K, value: this[K]) {
  this[key] = value;
  this.doSomeSideEffects();
}
```

Here's I'm using the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) to represent the type of the current object (so it should continue to work for subclasses if they add properties), and saying that `value` should be of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `this[K]`, meaning the type of the property of `this` at key `K`.

Let's test it out:

```
const x = new MyClass();
x.update("prop1", "abc"); // okay
x.update("prop2", "abc"); // error
// -------------> ~~~~~
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'
x.update("prop2", true); // okay
```

Looks good!

---

If you'd like to constrain `K` more so that nobody passes `"update"` or `"doSomeSideEffects"` in as `key`, you could use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to filter `keyof this`:

```
update<K extends Exclude<keyof this, "update" | "doSomeSideEffects">>(
  key: K, value: this[K]
) {

x.update("doSomeSideEffects", () => { }) // error!
// Argument of type '"doSomeSideEffects"' is
// not assignable to parameter of type '"prop1" | "prop2"'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! Really appreciate all the links so I can go learn about each piece.